Number of people required for every day of the year to have at least one birthday
Assuming every day of the year needs to have at least one birthday associated with it.
What is the number of people necessary for this to occur, with a probability of 99.999%?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem

@vallev That's about a different birthday problem.

Instead the relevant problem is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector%27s_problem

Let's make some simplifying assumptions, which are not realistic.

We ignore leap years, so there are $365$ possible days.
Each of $n$ people independently selects one of the $365$ days as birthday, with equal probabilities.

The total number of outcomes is $365^n$.
The number of outcomes such that all days are covered is  $365! S_2(n, 365)$, where $S_2(n, 365)$ is a Stirling number of the second kind (the number of ways to partition $n$ objects into $365$ nonempty sets).  Thus the probability that all days are covered is $365! S_2(n, 365)/365^n$.  The first $n$ that makes this
$\ge 0.99999$ is $n = 6347$.

Note that the approximation (falsely assuming independence between different days) $\dfrac{\log\left(1-0.99999^{1/365}\right)}{\log(364/365)} \approx 6346.968$ works well here
